# How to position two nav-bars?

Tags: html, css

I have created a design in Adobe XD, but I am struggling to get a second nav bar in the correct position. [Adobe XD Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viS57.png)

I have played around with the float element, but then it overlaps my background image for the hero image.

This is how it currently looks: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2mwH.jpg)

Please can someone put me in the right direction? Also noticed the Nav Bars are not responsive :(

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;1,500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    
    
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: smaller;

}


.logo {
    width: 12em;
    margin: 2em;
    left: 20px;
}

.top-navbar {
    float: right;
    font-size: smaller;
    
    
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    
}

.hero-image {
    background-image: url("https://www.midlandnetworks.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/midland-info-graphic-starter1-01-1900x500.png");
    display: block;
    height: 50vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.introduction-section {
    margin: 2em;
    
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    &::after {
        content: ' ';
        border-bottom: 5px solid #3274B9;
        display: block;
        width: 1.3em;
    }
}

h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-weight: 200;
}

.main-navbar{
    font-size: 1em;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Midland Networks | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-navigation">
           
                <img src="images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo">
           
        
        <nav class="top-navbar">

            <ul>
                <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Help Centre</li>
                <li>Downloads</li>
                <li>PBX Login</li>
                <li>Billing</li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        
    </div>

    <div class="main-navbar">
        <nav class="main">

            <ul>
                <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Help Centre</li>
                <li>Downloads</li>
                <li>PBX Login</li>
                <li>Billing</li>
            </ul>
    
        </nav>


    </div>
    
    <div class="hero-image">
       
    </div>

    <div class="introduction-section">
        <h1>Welcome to Midland Networks</h1>
        <h2>Business Telecom Specialists with over 30 years experience </h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="highlighted">


    </div>

    <div class="our-services">



    </div>

    <div class="contact-us">



    </div>

</body>
<footer>


</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: I think using `display: flex` instead of `float` would be appropriate for your case. How responsive do you want it to be? What would your navbars do when the screen gets narrower?

Comment: @tamarin I would like them to go into a hamburger menu. Should I do mobile coding or desktop coding first? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your float declarations and used `display: flex;` instead. You won't have problems with your navbars overlapping the hero-image anymore. To have the logo lining up with your second navbar you need to put it in the same div.

You could consider changing the names of your elements because you have a main-navigation and a main-navbar. Which one is the main?

Uncomment the background properties to see the space taken by each element.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;1,500&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.main-navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  /*background: lightblue;*/
}

.top-navbar {
  font-size: smaller;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url('https://www.midlandnetworks.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/midland-info-graphic-starter1-01-1900x500.png');
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.introduction-section {
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  &::after {
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3274B9;
    display: block;
    width: 1.3em;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.main-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1em;
  /*background: pink;*/
}

.logo {
  width: 12em;
  padding: 2em;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background: lightgreen;*/
}

.main ul{
  /*background: tomato;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Midland Networks | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-navigation">
      <nav class="top-navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
          <li>Help Centre</li>
          <li>Downloads</li>
          <li>PBX Login</li>
          <li>Billing</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="main-navbar">
     <img src="images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo" />
      <nav class="main">
        <ul>
          <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
          <li>Help Centre</li>
          <li>Downloads</li>
          <li>PBX Login</li>
          <li>Billing</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image"></div>

    <div class="introduction-section">
      <h1>Welcome to Midland Networks</h1>
      <h2>Business Telecom Specialists with over 30 years experience</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
        dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
        est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="highlighted"></div>

    <div class="our-services"></div>

    <div class="contact-us"></div>
  </body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

To have the logo lined up with the two navbars you need to put everything in the same div. The .main-navigation and the .navbars are flex containers. Here `display: grid;` would even be better than flex. You should consider checking that out.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;1,500&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.main-navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*background: black;*/
}

.top-navbar {
  font-size: smaller;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /*background: darkgrey;*/
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url('https://www.midlandnetworks.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/midland-info-graphic-starter1-01-1900x500.png');
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.introduction-section {
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  &::after {
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3274B9;
    display: block;
    width: 1.3em;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.navbars {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 12em;
  padding: 2em;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1em;
  /*background: lightgreen;*/
}

.main ul {
  margin-top: 2em;
  /*background: tomato;*/
}

.main ul li {
  /*background: white;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Midland Networks | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-navigation">
      <img src="images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo" />
      <div class="navbars">
        <nav class="top-navbar">
          <ul>
            <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Help Centre</li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
            <li>PBX Login</li>
            <li>Billing</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="main">
          <ul>
            <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Help Centre</li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
            <li>PBX Login</li>
            <li>Billing</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image"></div>

    <div class="introduction-section">
      <h1>Welcome to Midland Networks</h1>
      <h2>Business Telecom Specialists with over 30 years experience</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
        dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
        est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="highlighted"></div>

    <div class="our-services"></div>

    <div class="contact-us"></div>
  </body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The main-navbar is the main, but yes I will change the main-navigation as it is confusing. That was me messing about lol.

Comment: how can I get the main-navbar (second one) inline with the logo to the right, but still leave the first navbar in the top right corner please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks again, one final question: How can I position the logo so that it is in the middle of both the top nav and main nav? If I float the top nav to the right it does this, but messes everything else up...

Comment: I added a second snippet in the answer. As I mentioned, for this layout, the `grid` property would be even more appropriate.

Comment: brilliant, thank you.  I will do some research into CSS Grid. - i'm guessing grid replaces flex then..

Comment: You're welcome. Grid is more appropriate when you design your layout in 2 dimensions, but Flex is still great for 1 dimension layout, and as you saw it's not so complicated to use it for 2-dimension either, it's just not really built for it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;1,500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.logo {
  width: 12em;
  margin: 2em;
  left: 20px;
}

.top-navbar {
  font-size: smaller;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url("https://www.midlandnetworks.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/midland-info-graphic-starter1-01-1900x500.png");
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.introduction-section {
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  &::after {
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3274B9;
    display: block;
    width: 1.3em;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.main-navbar {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.logodiv {
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  height: 200px;
}

.main-navigation {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Midland Networks | Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <body>

    <div class="div-container">

      <div class="logodiv" style="   ">
        <img src="https://dynamic.brandcrowd.com/asset/logo/4bcc41b8-a669-4722-bf04-57fe2cd8dc7f/logo?v=4" class="logo" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="main-navigation">


        <nav class="top-navbar">

          <ul>
            <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Help Centre</li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
            <li>PBX Login</li>
            <li>Billing</li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
        <div class="main-navbar">
          <nav class="main">

            <ul>
              <li>0121 xxx xxx</li>
              <li>Contact Us</li>
              <li>About Us</li>
              <li>Help Centre</li>
              <li>Downloads</li>
              <li>PBX Login</li>
              <li>Billing</li>
            </ul>

          </nav>


        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="hero-image">

    </div>

    <div class="introduction-section">
      <h1>Welcome to Midland Networks</h1>
      <h2>Business Telecom Specialists with over 30 years experience </h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="highlighted">


    </div>

    <div class="our-services">



    </div>

    <div class="contact-us">



    </div>

  </body>
  <footer>


  </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Which element put the navbar inline with the logo? Was it having the logo in its own div, and then nav in another? Do web developers still use float as I just saw a YouTube video saying its an older method? Sorry, I am new to web dev and wanna gain a career in it aha

Comment: Check code. I put main wrapper then logo div and two menu wrapper

Comment: Have you check this ? @JamesSkinner

Comment: Thank you. :) just seen this aha.

Comment: This is another way to achieve result.